# Magento Coupon Code apply on original price and not on discounted price

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento-1.7

In my magento there are products with discounted price which gets applied from special_price attribute .
Now when i tried to create a Shopping cart price rule and created a coupon code, the coupon code discounted price gets calculated on discounted price.
But i want if the product is already under discounted price , coupon code discount should apply on base price and not on discounted price.
Please guide me how to setup this in magento.